# How to parse list of lists in order to tabulate it?

Tags: python-3.x, list, grouping

I have the following list, where when appear values for 'A', 'B' and 'D' is like a beginning of a new block of data, since the values for 'Q' and 'T' are associated with previous values of 'A', 'B' and 'D'.

```
L1 = [
         ['A','01'],['B','22'],['D','Srt'],
         ['Q','43'],['T','00'],
         ['Q','11'],['T','43'],
         ['A','01'],['B','52'],['D','Polt'],
         ['Q','84'],['T','39'],
         ['A','01'],['B','34'],['D','Jkq'],
         ['Q','81'],['T','13'],
         ['Q','17'],['T','68'],
         ['Q','77'],['T','15']
         ]
```

In image below I show the output table I'm looking for. I show with same colors, the values for 'Q' and 'T' that belong to values of A, B and D.

[image]

For second row in yellow, I fill down the values of A, B and D (01, 22, Srt)

For second and third rows in green, I fill down the values of A, B and D (01, 34, Jkq)

For row in blue, since there is only one pair of values for Q and T, then, there is only one row for A, B and D.

In order to feed Pandas DataFrame to tabulate it and get the desired table, I tried currently with below code and I'm getting this output.

```
dict = {}
for elem in L1:
    if elem[0] not in dict:
        dict[elem[0]] = []
    dict[elem[0]].append(elem[1:])

>>>
{
'A': [['01'], ['01'], ['01']], 
'B': [['22'], ['52'], ['34']], 
'D': [['Srt'], ['Polt'], ['Jkq']], 
'Q': [['43'], ['11'], ['84'], ['81'], ['17'], ['77']], 
'T': [['00'], ['43'], ['39'], ['13'], ['68'], ['15']]}
```

But the output should have the following structure:

```
Out={
  'A': ['01','01','01','01','01','01'],
  'B': ['22','22','52','34','34','34'],
  'D': ['Srt','Srt','Polt','Jkq','Jkq','Jkq'],
  'Q': ['43','11','84','81','17','77'],
  'T': ['00','43','39','13','68','15'],
}
```

in order to do `pandas.DataFrame(Out)`

How can I do this? thanks.

**UPDATE**

If the input list is like this:

```
L1 = [
         ['A','01'],['B','22'],['D','Srt'],
         ['Q','43'],['T','00'],
         ['Q','11'],['T','43'],
         ['A','01'],['B','52'],['D','Polt'],
         ['Q','84'],['T','39'],
         ['A','01'],['B','34'],['D','Jkq'],
         ['Q','81'],['T','13'],
         ['Q','17'],['T','68'],['R','05'],
         ['Q','77'],['T','15']
         ]
```

The output would be like this:

```
Out={
  'A': ['01','01','01','01','01','01'],
  'B': ['22','22','52','34','34','34'],
  'D': ['Srt','Srt','Polt','Jkq','Jkq','Jkq'],
  'Q': ['43','11','84','81','17','77'],
  'T': ['00','43','39','13','68','15'],
  'R': ['','','','','05','']
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Here is a sample [input file](https://jsfiddle.net/Le5jq4n0/) and this is the code I use to parse it and generate the list.

```
import re

f=open("file.txt","r").read().splitlines()

L1=[]
for line in f:
    if re.match(r'[ \t]', line):
        v.append(line.replace(' ', '').split('='))

L1
```

In this file, the values that begin a new "block" and that need to fill down are always A, B, D, and E. After E, could be 6 or 7 values that don't need to fill down (RDR, VS, RR, SA, GNA, UNA and/or SERRB), if some of these values don't always appear, leave in blank. The output table in this case would be like this:

[image]

Comment: why `R` in last row is empty and not `05`?

Comment: Good question. Because, the values after A, B, and D, let say, are the variable data, children of A, B and D that when they appear, always appear the 3 values. But values after D, could appear none (no Q, no T, no R) or more than one

Comment: In other words, is not needed the fill down when values are after A, B and D.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
import pandas as pd

L1 = [['A','01'],['B','22'],['D','Srt'],
      ['Q','43'],['T','00'],
      ['Q','11'],['T','43'],
      ['A','01'],['B','52'],['D','Polt'],
      ['Q','84'],['T','39'],
      ['A','01'],['B','34'],['D','Jkq'],
      ['Q','81'],['T','13'],
      ['Q','17'],['T','68'],
      ['Q','77'],['T','15']]

d = {}
li = []
for a,b in L1:
    d[a] = b      # update dictionary as elements are processed
    if a == 'T':  # but append a copy to the list when T is processed.
        li.append(d.copy())

df = pd.DataFrame(li)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    A   B     D   Q   T
0  01  22   Srt  43  00
1  01  22   Srt  11  43
2  01  52  Polt  84  39
3  01  34   Jkq  81  13
4  01  34   Jkq  17  68
5  01  34   Jkq  77  15
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works nice! one question. It could be that sometimes appear 2 values after A, B and D like Q and T, but sometimes could appear 2 or more, for example Q, T and R. How to modify the `if a == 'T':` to something more dynamic like if a == 'LastValue:? I've updated my original post to show a different input list and new output.

Comment: @GerCas Per your update, without a clear indication in the data when to flush a row, I'm not sure how you would handle the occasional extra data.  The input data needs another level of nesting, like ABD always grouped together, then additional parameters grouped like QT or QTR.  Can you change how the input is generated?

Comment: Hi Mark, I cannot change how the input is generated, since is taken from an txt file with certain format, that is read line by line and stored in the list I show as input. I was thinking in a way to count how many elements there are after D and the next A, to know which is the last one, but I don't know how to implement that

Comment: @GerCas Are you reading the file and storing it in the list?  It's the list structure that is ambiguous.  Can you share the input file instead?

Comment: Hi Mark. I've added a more representative sample file and output below my `UPDATE 2` in original post. Thanks for the help.